# List DependencyProperty always returning null

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

I have a custom control "ToolbarMenuButton" with the following DependencyProperty:

```
public ObservableCollection<object> TbMenuItems
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<object>)GetValue(TbMenuItemsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TbMenuItemsProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty TbMenuItemsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("TbMenuItems", typeof(ObservableCollection<object>), typeof(ToolbarMenuButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

I set it like so:

```
<customs:ToolbarMenuButton TbText="By Flight" TbIcon="PlaneRotated45"
                           TbMenuItems="{Binding Flights}"
                           TbItemCommand="{Binding FlightSelect}">
```

And it shows up, no problem. Now, there's a click handler for this button in the custom control that makes sure the context menu is set, and if it isn't, it creates a new one based on the dependencyproperty "TbMenuItems" shown above.

**The Error:**
This property is always null (I get a null exception in runtime when I click the button). I've been through about 40 stackoverflow answers regarding this they are either N/A or didn't fix it. As I understand, get/set on dependency properties don't get called, but I'm not sure how then I'm ever supposed to get the data from it.

**What I've Tried:**
I've tried notifying property changed when Flights is set. I've ensured Flights is set by putting one of them in a textblock right next to the button (so I also know the datacontext and path, etc are all correct). I've changed this to an observable collection (was originally a list) to see if that helped. The other dependency properties all seem to work just fine (of course, they are also bound to the data template in the style, not sure if that matters). I'm not sure where to go, now.

Comment: When you say the property is null, you mean `TbMenuItems="{Binding Flights}"` isn't working? But `TbItemCommand="{Binding FlightSelect}"` does work? Besides that, why is it an ObservableCollection? Do you intend to add elements after the property values has been set.

Comment: `PropertyMetadata` has a callback you can register as it's second parameter.  See if it is getting hit.

Comment: @Clemens -- I don't know if the command is working because I can't get the menu open to click an option, but the other two properties work. It's an observable collection because that was an answer in another thread that I tried, it was originally list.

Comment: @MrZander - I'll try that when I get back to my computer

Comment: @linus72982 It surely doesn't need to be an ObservableCollection, at least not if you don't want to attach a CollectionChanged event handler. Besides that, "the other two properties work", sure, because they are not bound. My guess is that you have explicitly set the control's DataContext, which breaks any DataContext based Bindings of its dependency properties.

Comment: Sadly that's not it, either, as I've also tried relative binding to parent and explicitly setting datacontext to the one I need.

Comment: @MrZander -- I tried the callback, it doesn't get called even after I click the button

Comment: @Clemens -- I just verified the command property is getting set properly with a breakpoint, it's just the TbMenuItems that isn't getting set

Comment: Did you check the Output Window in Visual Studio for Binding error messages? What is the type of the `Flights` property. You need to add more details to your question.

Comment: @Clemens -- Never knew about the Binding errors in output, that found my problem -- cannot convert from type List<Flight> to List<object> -- I thought using List<object> would catch any List I threw at it -- not sure how to tell it to accept what I give it. I don't use any type-specific methods, just ToString. But I need the whole object as the command parameter, so I can't just expose a new property of List<string> with the names. Hmm

Comment: I tried dynamic, too -- no dice :S

Comment: `public IEnumerable TbMenuItems { ... }`. Like ItemsSource of an ItemsControl.

Comment: Perfect! That works splendidly. If you want to put it in an answer, I'll mark it.  Thanks for sticking with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using a too specific type for your collection-type property, which is not assignment compatible with the value produced by the data binding.

You should instead use the most generic collection type that can possibly be used, usually `IEnumerable`:

```
public IEnumerable TbMenuItems
{
    get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(TbMenuItemsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TbMenuItemsProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty TbMenuItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    nameof(TbMenuItems), typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(ToolbarMenuButton));
```